# How to add to numbers in println after a string

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Wrong. correct answer is " 5 + 7);
```

This outputs: 
Wrong. correct answer is 57
I want it to output: 
Wrong. correct answer is 12

Comment: Code doesn't compile.

Comment: `System.out.print("Wrong. correct answer is " + (5 + 7));`.  Use parenthesis just like you would in math.

Comment: System.out.print("Wrong. correct answer is "+(5 + 7));

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in this case you are combine two strings : string 5 and string 7. The result is 57. If you want to add two numbers, then use the following code:

```
int result = 5 + 7;
System.out.print("Wrong. correct answer is " + result);
```

Comment: Actually, you would be concatenating Strings - since you can't "add" them.

Comment: I wanted to say that in this case 5 + 7 add up not as numbers, but as strings. Thanks for mixing

Answer (score 0):

We can also use printf, it allows formatting as well.

```
System.out.printf("Wrong. correct answer is %d", 5 + 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the system see the numbers as a string then add them to your string message. To add any mathematical value to a string you should save the numbers in integer values and calculate it in another integer value and then add this value to your message as a string. so you can write the code like this:

```
int FirstNumber = 5;
int SecondNumber = 7;
int Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
System.out.print("Wrong. correct answer is " + Result);
```

but if the message is constant, then it's better to write it all in string just like this:

```
System.out.print("Wrong. correct answer is 12");
```